# Tkinter fonts are blury and pixelated

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, fonts

I am trying to make a GUI in Ubuntu 16.04, python 3.6 running the code using virtual environment. I have many default fonts installed on my system.

[image]

No matter what code I try my GUI can't seem to use them. The fonts looks really bad, blurry and pixelated:

[image]

The list of fonts that the GUI keep using are only these:

[image]

I tried to set the fonts using:

```
style.configure('TLabelframe.Label',background='#f5f6fa',font=("Helvetica",14))
```

and

```
tab_Font = Font(family="Lato", size=13)
```

When I tried this code:

```
print(Font(font='Lato 13').actual())
```

It displays:

```
{'family': 'fixed', 'size': 13, 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'underline': 0, 'overstrike': 0}
```

which means `fixed` font is used instead of `Lato`.

I have fonts in `/usr/share/fonts`. I also have fonts in `/home/minhaj/.fonts` so that's not the problem of fonts not installed.

I simply want to use some decent fonts so that my application doesn't look that bad.

Comment: Share a screenshot please

Comment: All the screenshots are attached via link as I cannot add images directly.

Comment: Does it do the same bad font thing when you set the font directly to the label: `tk.Label(master, font="Helvetica 13")`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which reproduces the problem on your system. Also, you show the system having only a dozen fonts, then you show code trying to use a font not in the list. Have you tried setting it to one of the fonts in that last image?